# Ext JS form.getValues() retrieves bad values for checkboxes

Tags: extjs, checkbox

So I have a `form` with two `checkbox`es. When I call `form.getForm().getValues()` and I log the `values`, it retrieves `checkbox` values like this: if it is checked then the value looks like this - `SomeCheckbox: "on"`, and if it's not checked than the value is not there at all. And then I encode those values into `JSON` and send it to ASP.NET MVC and the values ASP retrieves for these `checkboxes` are always false. The solution I came up with is to set the `SomeCheckbox` properties of the `values` I retrieve from `form` after getting `form` values and it works just fine, but is not there any other way ?

> SOLUTION:
>
> call `form`'s `getFieldValues()` method instead of `getValues()`

Comment: please, post your solution as answer and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call form's getFieldValues() method instead of getValues()

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an inputValue config to the checkbox.

```
{
    boxLabel  : 'Anchovies',
    name      : 'topping',
    inputValue: 'anchovies'
}
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Checkbox-cfg-inputValue